# Singletons in Heterogenous Lists

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, data-kinds, singleton-type

I'd like to write a function which analyzes a heterogenous list. For sake of argument, let's have the following

```
data Rec rs where
  Nil :: Rec '[]
  Cons :: ty -> Rec rs -> Rec ( '(name, ty) ': rs )

class Analyze name ty where
  analyze :: Proxy name -> ty -> Int
```

The ultimate goal would be to write something like the following

```
class AnalyzeRec rs where
  analyzeRec :: Rec rs -> [(String, Int)]

instance AnalyzeRec '[] where
  analyzeRec Nil = []

instance (Analyze name ty, AnalyzeRec rs) => 
           AnalyzeRec ( '(name, ty) ': rs ) 
  where
    analyzeRec (Cons hd tl) = 
      let proxy = Proxy :: Proxy name
      in (symbolVal proxy, analyze proxy hd) : analyzeRec tl
```

The salient bits being that `analyzeRec` uses knowledge of constraints instantiated at each type and value in the `Rec`. This class-based mechanism works, but is clunky and verbose in the case where you have to do this over and over (and I do).

So, I'd like to instead replace this with a [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons)-based mechanism. I'd like to write instead a function like

```
-- no type class!
analyzeRec :: All Analyze rs => Rec rs -> [(String, Int)]
analyzeRec rec = 
  case rec of
    Nil -> []
    Cons hd tl -> withSing $ \s -> 
      (symbolVal s, analyze s hd) : analyzeRec tl
```

but this clearly falls flat in at least a few dimensions.

What is the "right" way to write such a function over heterogenous lists using the Singletons technique? Is there a better way to approach this problem? What should I expect in solving this sort of thing?

(For reference, this is for an experimental Servant clone called Serv. The relevant files are [`Serv.Internal.Header.Serialization`](https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons-header-special/src/Serv/Internal/Header/Serialization.hs) and [`Serv.Internal.Header`](https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons-header-special/src/Serv/Internal/Header.hs) as background. I'd like to write a function which takes in a heterogenous list of tagged header values and then `headerEncode` them into a list of actual `(ByteString, ByteString)` pairs.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to present here an "idiomatic" `singletons` solution (if such a thing even exists). Preliminaries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  RankNTypes, DataKinds, PolyKinds, ConstraintKinds, GADTs,
  TypeOperators, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Exts (Constraint) 

-- SingI constraint here for simplicity's sake
class SingI name => Analyze (name :: Symbol) ty where
  analyze :: Proxy name -> ty -> Int

data Rec rs where
  Nil :: Rec '[]
  Cons :: ty -> Rec rs -> Rec ( '(name, ty) ': rs )

recName :: Rec ('(name, t) ': rs) -> Proxy name
recName _ = Proxy
```

We need an `All c rs` constraint, but we give it a spin and make `c` a `TyFun` instead a plain `a -> Constraint` constructor:

```
type family AllC (c :: TyFun a Constraint -> *) (rs :: [a]) :: Constraint where
  AllC c '[]       = ()
  AllC c (x ': xs) = (c @@ x, AllC c xs)
```

`TyFun` lets us abstract over type constructors **and** type families and gives us partial application. It gives us almost first-class type-level functions with a somewhat ugly syntax. Note though that we necessarily lose constructor injectivity. `@@` is the operator for applying `TyFun`-s. `TyFun a b -> *` means that `a` is the input and `b` is the output, and the trailing `-> *` is just an artifact of the encoding. With GHC 8.0 we'll be able to just do

```
type a ~> b = TyFun a b -> *
```

And use `a ~> b` thereafter.

We can implement now a general "classy" mapping over `Rec`:

```
cMapRec ::
  forall c rs r.
  AllC c rs => Proxy c -> (forall name t. (c @@ '(name, t)) => Proxy name -> t -> r) -> Rec rs -> [r]
cMapRec p f Nil           = []
cMapRec p f r@(Cons x xs) = f (recName r) x : cMapRec p f xs
```

Note that above `c` has kind `TyFun (a, *) Constraint -> *`.

And then implement `analyzeRec`:

```
analyzeRec :: 
  forall c rs. (c ~ UncurrySym1 (TyCon2 Analyze)) 
  => AllC c rs => Rec rs -> [(String, Int)]
analyzeRec = cMapRec (Proxy :: Proxy c) (\p t -> (fromSing $ singByProxy p, analyze p t))
```

First, `c ~ UncurrySym1 (TyCon2 Analyze)` is just a type-level `let` binding that lets me use `c` in `Proxy c` as a shorthand. (If I really wanted to use all the dirty tricks, I would add `{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}` and write `Proxy :: _ c`).

`UncurrySym1 (TyCon2 Analyze)` does the same thing that `uncurry Analyze` would do if Haskell had full support for type level functions. The obvious advantage here is that we can write out the type of `analyzeRec` on the fly without extra top-level type families or classes, and also use `AllC` far more generally.

---

As a bonus, let's remove the `SingI` constraint from `Analyze`, and try to implement `analyzeRec`.

```
class Analyze (name :: Symbol) ty where
  analyze :: Proxy name -> ty -> Int
```

Now we have to require an additional constraint that expresses that all the `name`-s in our `Rec` are `SingI`. We can use two `cMapRec`-s, and zip the results:

```
analyzeRec ::
  forall analyze names rs.  
  (analyze ~ UncurrySym1 (TyCon2 Analyze),
   names   ~ (TyCon1 SingI :.$$$ FstSym0),
   AllC analyze rs,
   AllC names rs)
  => Rec rs -> [(String, Int)]
analyzeRec rc = zip
  (cMapRec (Proxy :: Proxy names)   (\p _ -> fromSing $ singByProxy p) rc)
  (cMapRec (Proxy :: Proxy analyze) (\p t -> analyze p t) rc)
```

Here `TyCon1 SingI :.$$$ FstSym0` can be translated as `SingI . fst`.

This is still roughly within the level of abstraction that can be readily expressed with `TyFun`-s. The main limitation, of course, is the lack of lambdas. Ideally we wouldn't have to use `zip`, instead we would use `AllC (\(name, t) -> (SingI name, Analyze name t))`, and use a single `cMapRec`. With `singletons`, if we can't wing it anymore with point-free type-level programming, we have to introduce a new pointful type family.

Amusingly, GHC 8.0 will be strong enough so that we can implement type-level lambdas from scratch, although it will be probably ugly as hell. For example, `\p -> (SingI (fst p), uncurry Analyze p)` could look something like this:

```
Eval (
  Lam "p" $
    PairL :@@
      (LCon1 SingI :@@ (FstL :@@ Var "p")) :@@    
      (UncurryL :@@ LCon2 Analyze :@@ Var "p"))
```

where all the `L` postfixes denote the lambda term embeddings of ordinary `TyFun`-s (yet another collection of shorthands to be generated by TH...).

I have a [prototype](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/c7d385aa117929503feb), although it only works with the even uglier de Bruijn variables yet, because of a GHC bug. It also features `Fix` and explicit laziness on the type level.

Comment: Awesome! I had just figured out something like `AllC` and had been stuck on understanding the function symbols. I think I can make this work. I feel like going the full cMap route is too far at the moment, but it's close to feasible!

Comment: Feel free to ask about `TyFun`-s. They do involve a lot of syntactic noise, and it's likely worth an exposition. Also, you could look at [this](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/defunctionalization-for-the-win/), if you haven't read it already.

Comment: I skimmed that post a while back but I think now I have the background to better understand it, thanks again for the reference!

Comment: Here are some attempts to wedge this into my code: https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons/src/Serv/Internal/Query.hs https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons/src/Serv/Internal/MediaType.hs and https://github.com/tel/serv/blob/feat-singletons/src/Serv/Internal/Header.hs. I'll want to get confident with these techniques before diving into `Server.hs`.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a sound approach, it's just that .. sometimes you need to help the type system out a bit.

Firstly, the way you write the `All` predicate matters a lot (if it reduces at the proper times) and I don't know which `All` you are using.

Also, you are using `symbolVal` on the name but there is no proof that it is a `KnownSymbol` - you must add this proof somewhere. The only obvious place, to me, is on the type class:

```
class KnownSymbol name => Analyze name ty where
  analyze :: Proxy name -> ty -> Int
```

Here is the `All` predicate:

```
type family All (c :: k -> Constraint) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint where 
  All c '[] = () 
  All c (x ': xs) = (c x, All c xs)
```

Note that this line

```
analyzeRec :: All Analyze rs => Rec rs -> [(String, Int)]
```

does not type check (it is not well kinded). Each element of `rs` is a tuple. We could write `All' :: (k0 -> k1 -> Constraint) -> [(k0,k1)] -> Constraint` directly much in the same way as `All'`. But it is funner to write a type class `Uncurry`:

```
type family Fst (x :: (k0, k1)) :: k0 where 
  Fst '(x,y) = x 

type family Snd (x :: (k0, k1)) :: k1 where 
  Snd '(x,y) = y 

class (c (Fst x) (Snd x)) => Uncurry (c :: k0 -> k1 -> Constraint) (x :: (k0, k1)) where 
instance (c x y) => Uncurry c '(x, y)
```

If this `Uncurry` looks exceedingly complicated, it is again because it is important for `Uncurry c '(x,y)` to reduce to `c x y` at the right time, so it is written in a way that forces (or rather allows) the typechecker to reduce this constraint whenever it sees it. Now the function is

```
analyzeRec :: All (Uncurry Analyze) rs => Rec rs -> [(String, Int)]
analyzeRec r = 
  case r of
    Nil -> []
    (Cons hd tl) -> let s = recName r in (symbolVal s, analyze s hd) : analyzeRec tl

-- Helper
recName :: Rec ('(name,ty)':rs) -> Proxy name 
recName _ = Proxy
```

This doesn't use anything from `singletons` nor does it need it.

---

Complete working code

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, ConstraintKinds, UndecidableInstances, TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-} 

import Data.Proxy 
import GHC.TypeLits 
import GHC.Prim (Constraint)

data Rec rs where
  Nil :: Rec '[]
  Cons :: ty -> Rec rs -> Rec ( '(name, ty) ': rs )

class KnownSymbol name => Analyze name ty where
  analyze :: Proxy name -> ty -> Int

type family All (c :: k -> Constraint) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint where 
  All c '[] = () 
  All c (x ': xs) = (c x, All c xs) 

type family Fst (x :: (k0, k1)) :: k0 where 
  Fst '(x,y) = x 

type family Snd (x :: (k0, k1)) :: k1 where 
  Snd '(x,y) = y 

class (c (Fst x) (Snd x)) => Uncurry (c :: k0 -> k1 -> Constraint) (x :: (k0, k1)) where 
instance (c x y) => Uncurry c '(x, y)

recName :: Rec ('(name,ty)':rs) -> Proxy name 
recName _ = Proxy 

analyzeRec :: All (Uncurry Analyze) rs => Rec rs -> [(String, Int)]
analyzeRec r = 
  case r of
    Nil -> []
    (Cons hd tl) -> let s = recName r in (symbolVal s, analyze s hd) : analyzeRec tl
```

Comment: Huh, I thought I tried this in the past and it broke down. I'll try following your code example closely, now. Thanks!

Comment: @dfeuer `class (...) => Uncurry c '(x, y)` is simply not a valid class declaration.. and `instance (c (Fst x) (Snd x)) => Uncurry c x` is perfectly valid and the code works just the same.. the other version is just less characters to type.

Comment: Oh, right, silly me. So the obvious way, I suppose, is `class (c p q, x ~ '(p, q)) => Uncurry c x`. Is that problematic?

Comment: No because that also isn't a valid class declaration, all the variables in the left hand side must appear in the right hand side.

Comment: Buh. I'm failing today. Thanks.